# WinForm popup forms relationships with parent

Tags: c#, winforms

Okay, I have a WinForms C# program I am writing in Visual Studio 2010 Express. This program has two forms, the main form called "MainForm", and a secondary form called "ConfigForm". The MainForm has a button on it which pops up the ConfigForm.

```
    private void buttonConfig_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new ConfigForm().Show();
    }
```

Right now, when you click the button, the ConfigForm pops up wherever it feels like it. It doesn't necessarily pop up over the MainForm. How do I get it to popup on top of the main form? I have tried setting ConfigForm's StartPosition to CenterParent, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

For that matter, how do I "lock" the program while the ConfigForm is open. When the ConfigForm is open, I would prefer if the user doesn't have the ability to navigate back to the MainForm.

Comment: Have you tried `new ConfigForm().Show(this);`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
private void buttonConfig_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (ConfigForm cf = new ConfigForm()) {
    cf.ShowDialog(this);
  }
}
```

And yes, make sure that `ConfigForm.StartPosition = CenterParent` as you noted.

On the ConfigForm form, you can have your buttons set the `DialogResults` of the form, like this:

```
void buttonOK(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
  this.Close();
}
```

Then your calling convention can be:

```
private void buttonConfig_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (ConfigForm cf = new ConfigForm()) {
    if (cf.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) {
      // do something the user said was ok
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah... .Show() VS .ShowDialog... I never knew the difference. Why are you using "using" here?

Comment: It calls dispose on the ConfigForm when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @JasonAxelrod ShowDialog basically locks the program on the pop-up form so the user can't do anything else but answer the dialog.  The `using` block will conveniently dispose of the form after it's closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the ShowDialog method.